# Websphere MQ JMS - Configuration Options

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I am currently successfully using an MQConnectionFactory to connect and post to a Websphere MQ queue using JMS.

However I'm getting a requirement from a client that I must use mqclient.ini instead.

So my question is, for a 'standard' JMS setup, should I be using:

- Straight up [MQConnectionFactory](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQConnectionFactory.html) instance
- [A JMS configuration file](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm41100_.htm)
- An [mqclient.ini](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.1.0/com.ibm.mq.doc/cs13350_.htm) file

?  What would one use one over the other?  Does one take precedence over another?

Comment: Please tell us the reason for using JMS Config or MQClient.ini file?

Comment: Client requirement, unf.  What I'm trying to do is convince them that the factory settings will suffice but I can't do that w/out understanding the other options.

Answer (score 0):

The mqclient.ini and JMSconfig files are used setting attributes like what client side exits to use, TCP level overrides etc. They are basically used for configuring the client libraries/jars. They are not meant for application configuration for example what queue manager or queue to use. This sort of info, connection factory or destination info, is typically pulled from a JNDI so that the configuration can be modified without affecting application.

Comment: In what scenario does one use mqclient over JMSconfig?